# Adding a "my messages (x)" link in the block template file

Tags: theming

I have installed [Privatemsg](http://drupal.org/project/privatemsg), and I need to output the "My messages (x)" link programmatically in block.tpl.php.

I tried the following code, but it only prints "My Messages", when I need a counter for the new messages:

```
print l('My messages', 'messages');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function [privatemsg_title_callback()](http://api.worldempire.ch/api/privatemsg/privatemsg.module/function/privatemsg_title_callback/7-1) like this:

```
print l(privatemsg_title_callback(), 'messages');
```

And as marcvangend mentioned, Privatemsg already provides a block that informs the user if he has new messages and a block that contains exactly such a link and additionally a link to write a new private message. Why not use one of these instead?

Comment: I've created individual block for users, to edit their profiles, content etc. I mean, i manually added such links:

<?php
print l('add blog entry', 'node/add/blog');
...and so on
?>

So i needed to manually create a link to "my messages (x)"

Answer (score 3):

The module already contains a block that does something similar: "New message indication". You can use that block and alter the output if needed by overriding the theme_privatemsg_new_block() function.